# Storing SRT values for skeletal animation

Tags: animation, matrix

I'm currently developing a skeletal animation system for my current project. I guess I understand how it works after doing a lot of reading but while looking at the source of some different projects, I was wondering however why the scale, rotation and translation values of each bone are stored seperately. You could store all of them within a single matrix right? Wouldn't that be more efficient, or would you need more math to get the seperate values rendering it less efficient?

Also while I'm at it, apparently there are 2 common ways of storing the values, which is by matrices, or using vectors and quaternions. The latter one being used more frequently to avoid gimbal lock. However my project has only 2 degrees of freedom. What would be the most efficient way to store my values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a matrix wouldn't be more efficient because you would have to use a 4x4 matrix, so 16 floats. This is mainly because of the way rotation + translation are stored in the matrix.

If you store the values in SRT form you end up with 9 floats, as the rotation quaternion's w component can be re-computed from the others on load.

Moreover many game engines do not support non-uniform scaling, so you can shrink to 1 float for the scale and end up with 8 floats per bones !

And that's before compression: since you know that bones won't move past a certain point (they are volume-bound) then there is no point allocating precision to those ranges it will never reach, so you can encode those floats down to say 16-bit, so you end up with 4 floats per bones.

Now to be fair, I've never implemented that last part with compression; it seemed a bit extreme to me and I didn't have the time.

But going from 64 bytes per bones to 32 bytes per bone is 50% saving !